# Searching for hidden key-value pairs in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, keyvaluepair

I need to extract very specific key-value pairs from a dictionary. The keys are whole numbers and the values repeat for a certain number of keys, which varies. 
I must extract the last key-value pair for the repeated value. So, in this case, I need to extract the key-value pairs:

```
42: ['e ']
85: ['dis ']
88: ['d ']
95: ['e ']
```

The number of times a certain value appears is random. A value may appear again later, as is the present case with the value ['e '], and so I need to extract it twice.

This is the example I'm using here for the type of dictonary I'm dealing with:

```
notes_dict = {
    0: ['e '], 
    1: ['e '], 
    2: ['e '], 
    3: ['e '], 
    #(...)
    40: ['e '], 
    41: ['e '], 
    42: ['e '], 
    43: ['dis '], 
    44: ['dis '], 
    45: ['dis '],
    #(...)
    83: ['dis '], 
    84: ['dis '], 
    85: ['dis '], 
    86: ['d '], 
    87: ['d '], 
    88: ['d '], 
    89: ['e '], 
    90: ['e '], 
    91: ['e '], 
    92: ['e '], 
    93: ['e '], 
    94: ['e '], 
    95: ['e ']
}
```

Idea behind this: this dictionary contais information about which musical note is being played at a given time. I need to make this process automatic in order to try and plot a very simplified sheet music.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: That said, what is your question?  It appears that you need to get the last value of every group, just before the note changes.  Using a dictionary for this is weird; a time series is generally a sequence (ordered series of values, a tuple or list).

Comment: You are right: I need to get the last value of every group, just before the note changes.
So, are you saying that I should turn my dictionary into a list to solve this?

Comment: prune is correct, a dict is a bad structure, dicts are unordered so there is no notion of what comes first or last based in the key number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
from itertools import groupby
notes_dict = {
    0: ['e '],
    1: ['e '],
    2: ['e '],
    3: ['e '],
    40: ['e '],
    41: ['e '],
    42: ['e '],
    43: ['dis '],
    44: ['dis '],
    45: ['dis '],
    83: ['dis '],
    84: ['dis '],
    85: ['dis '],
    86: ['d '],
    87: ['d '],
    88: ['d '],
    89: ['e '],
    90: ['e '],
    91: ['e '],
    92: ['e '],
    93: ['e '],
    94: ['e '],
    95: ['e ']
}

for k, g in groupby(sorted(notes_dict),
                    key=notes_dict.get):
    print '{}: {}'.format(list(g)[-1], k)
```

Comment: Gosh, you people are fast... Would probably better with a bit of explanation.

Comment: It is difficult to know what part to explain, given that your original post did not have any specific question in it. For your next post to Stack Overflow, please include a specific question, along with some code that you've written to solve the problem on your own. Doing so will encourage people to respond with explanations, and not just code samples. Please see [ask] before your next post.

Answer (score 0):

Having a dict to represent these is probably a bad idea since dictionaries are not internally sorted by key. You're probably better off having a list of tuples or something. Maybe even a pandas Series for that matter.

Anyhow, you can probably use the standard library's `itertools` to do what you want:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> notes = sorted((k, v[0]) for k, v in notes_dict.items())
>>> dict(list(g)[-1] for _, g in itertools.groupby(notes, lambda x: x[1]))
{42: 'e ', 85: 'dis ', 88: 'd ', 95: 'e '}
```

P.S. there's a few nice libraries for working with notes and sheet music, you may to take a look at [mingus](http://bspaans.github.io/python-mingus/) and [abjad](http://abjad.mbrsi.org/index.html) for instance.

Comment: I'm using librosa to make a chromagram and the LilyPond engraver to plot the notes.

Comment: @Capriles Sounds great! Both mingus and abjad support LilyPond backend for sheet music rendering, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you should turn this into a list of character strings:

```
pitch = ['e', 'e', ..., 'dis', ..., 'd', ..., 'e', ... 'e', 'dummy']
```

Now, the output is more like

```
print_list = [(i, pitch[i]) for i in range(len(pitch)) if pitch[i] != pitch[i+1])
```

However, if this is the only use you need to make of your dictionary, then I recommend the earlier answers that work with your current format.